# Table Tennis Double 'Let' Rules

Tags: rules, table-tennis, serve

Imagine a table tennis board divided into the usual 4 rectangles. From top-left going clockwise we have A1, A2, B2 and B1 (in that order). B1, B2 and A1, A2 are on opposite sides of the net.

In a doubles match, we start by serving from B2->A1. During the serve, if the ball hits the net and then falls into A2, is it called **a wrong serve or a let?**

Comment: @PhilipKendall - I'm looking for a clarification of a specific 'Lets' rule in Table Tennis and hence believe my question is distinct from the suggested duplicate.

Comment: @Yaitzme See the text : `provided the service is otherwise good`.